# getContext alternative for graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I'm using the `graphql-java-kickstart` library in Spring Boot and have some code like so:

```
class MyResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    public String helloWorld(DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
        // this works!!
        CustomGraphQLContext context = env.getContext();
        return "Hello world";
    } 
}
```

I've built the context elsewhere using the `GraphQLServletContextBuilder`.

The problem is that `getContext` is deprecated. It says to alternatively use `getGraphQLContext`, but it's currently null for me. How do I get it populated? If I need to override the `ExecutionInput`, where do I do that?